# Hana: How do I create a tuple of types from a variant?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, boost-hana

If I have a variant, like so:

```
using my_variant = boost::variant<int, bool, std::string>;
```

Is there an easy way to extract the types the variant can contain into a Boost.Hana tuple so that the following holds:

```
using boost::hana::type;
static_assert(std::is_same<my_tuple, boost::hana::tuple<type<int>, type<bool>, type<std::string>>>{});
```

Comment: Just to clarify; do you want a `hana::tuple<int, bool, std::string>`, or a `hana::tuple<hana::type<int>, hana::type<bool>, hana::type<std::string>>`. In other words, do you want a tuple of the __types__, or a tuple containing __objects__ whose types are that of the variant?

Comment: a tuple of types. edited the question :)

Comment: although something generic to do either, ala `meta::as_list` would be good (is there one? couldn't see it in the docs)

Comment: Nope, there's none right now. However, I've been thinking about this for a while, but I never really found a satisfying name for it: https://github.com/boostorg/hana/issues/67. However, we'll be able to use the fact that  `boost::variant<>::types` is an MPL sequence. I'm writing up my answer.

Comment: If you need this functionality for arbitrary templates, let's discuss it on https://github.com/boostorg/hana/issues/67. I do agree that it would be useful, but I just need a little bit of convincing and some help with the naming of such a functionality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following will work on `develop` (since [e13d826](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/commit/e13d826496192af4c4228210a2b6661174c9a55a)):

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/ext/boost/mpl.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <string>
namespace hana = boost::hana;


using my_variant = boost::variant<int, bool, std::string>;

constexpr auto my_tuple = hana::to<hana::tuple_tag>(my_variant::types{});

// Note:
// In general, don't use std::is_same to compare hana::tuple; use == in
// because it will also work if the tuple contains hana::basic_types.
static_assert(my_tuple == hana::tuple_t<int, bool, std::string>, "");
```

What [e13d826](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/commit/e13d826496192af4c4228210a2b6661174c9a55a) did was add support for `mpl::list`; only `mpl::vector` was supported before, and `boost::variant<>::types` is a `mpl::list`. This is why my answer took a while to come; I was implementing that :-).

**Edit**

I did not explain why I'm using `constexpr auto my_tuple = ...` instead of `using my_tuple = decltype(...)`. Well, the reason is simply because knowing the type of `my_tuple` is not really useful, since you can't rely on it. Indeed, if you look at the documentation of `hana::type`, it's written that you can't rely on `hana::type<T>` being anything specific. There are good reasons for this, but from a usability point of view it means that you can't rely on the type of `hana::tuple<hana::type<...>, ...>` being anything specific either. When doing type-level computations, prefer value-level encoding (thus `auto my_tuple = ...`) to type-level encoding. This is the specificity of Hana over MPL & friends, and you should try to stick with it as much as possible, or you'll find Hana to be really clunky (because not written with that in mind).

Comment: this is amazing, thanks! although a solution for general typelists would think would be very helpful for integrating hana into any existing codebase / library

Comment: It just occurred to me that one should be careful with a general specialization-based solution. Indeed, some library components use an emulation of variadic templates, and `xxx<int, bool, char>` is instead `xxx<int, bool, char, mpl::void_, ...>`. I just checked, and `boost::variant` uses real variadic templates if the compiler supports it, so it would work now. But we must still be cautious in the general case.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't use any hana features, but should work.

First, a `transcribe` type function that takes a template, and an instance of a different template, and transcribes the types in the second into the first:

```
template<template<class...>class To, class From>
struct transcribe;
template<template<class...>class To, class From>
using transcribe_t=typename transcribe<To,From>::type;

template<template<class...>class Z, template<class...>class Src, class...Ts>
struct transcribe<Z, Src<Ts...>> {
  using type=Z<Ts...>;
};
```

Now, a template that takes types, and returns a hana tuple of hana types:

```
template<class...Ts>
using tuple_of_types = boost::hana::tuple<boost::hana::type<Ts>...>;
```

And we are done:

```
template<class Src>
using get_types_from = transcribe_t< tuple_of_types, Src >;

using result = get_types_from< my_variant >;
```

`get_types_from` is because a type function that extracts the template arguments of an arbitrary template seems useful.

Answer (score 2):

Some time back I had come across something similar to this for such conversion. Not able to find the actual source of this idea though or it may be even a pretty common practice:

```
template<class From, template<class...> class To> struct convert_impl;

template<template<class...> class From, class... Types, 
         template<class...> class To>
struct convert_impl<From<Types...>, To>
{
    using converted_type = To<Types...>;
};

template<class From, template<class...> class To>
using convert = typename convert_impl<From, To>::converted_type;
```

Since, I am not sure about boost hana tuple, I will show an example with std::tuple

```
convert<boost::variant<int, bool, string>, std::tuple>
```